# Is it possible to add non-persistent attributes to Laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, eloquent

I'm creating an API with Laravel (Lumen) in which there are objects which contain a field which is a path to a file.
These paths are stored as relative paths in the database but upon returning them to user I have to convert them to absolute urls.

Now I was wondering if there is a convenient way to add a non-persistent field to the model objects. Obviously there are [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) but they are persisted to the database.

I also have thought of creating an after-middleware which traverses the object tree and converts every `path` field it finds but this is not an elegant way.

Here is the final transformation I need:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Some title",
    "media": [
      {
        "id": 435,
        "path": "relative/path/to/some/file.ext"
      },
      {
        "id": 436,
        "path": "relative/path/to/some/file2.ext"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Some title",
    "media": [
      {
        "id": 435,
        "url": "http://example.com/relative/path/to/some/file.ext"
      },
      {
        "id": 436,
        "url": "http://example.com/relative/path/to/some/file2.ext"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Laravel accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators),

**From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):**

> The original value of the column is passed to the accessor, allowing
>   you to manipulate and return the value.

These are not persisted in the DB but are modified as and when you access them.

**For example:**

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$firstName = $user->first_name;
```

**In your use case:**

Define an accessor in the **Media Model** for path attribute.

```
public function getPathAttribute($value)
{
    return storage_path($value);
}
```

**If you need to access the property with a different name (alias):**

```
public function getAliasAttribute()
{
    return storage_path($this->attributes['path']);
}
// $model->alias
```

Comment: Excellent, -1 point for me for not reading the docs thoroughly. Thanks man.

Comment: @HamedMomeni Please see the updated answer too I have added an example relevant to your use case

Comment: Thanks again, but is there way to change the field name itself?

Comment: @HamedMomeni Yes you can. Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

As @Sapnesh Naik said what you need is a simple [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) like this:

```
public function getPathAttribute($value)
{
    $url = config('relative_url') or env('PATH') or $sthElse;
    return $url.$this->attributes['path'];
}
```